# .Net One Click Publishing to Sharepoint

Tags: .net, sharepoint, ftp, desktop-application, oneclick

### Background

The company I work for is migrating their FTP servers to SharePoint 2016 and retiring their old infrastructure.

However I am yet to work out how I am going to distribute our internal software to colleagues in office.

Currently after completing a project, I'll publish the desktop application to the ftpserver via the One-click publishing settings in Visual Studio. Then share the location of the published software, from which users can install the software on to their local machines.

### Question

Is a similar setup available using SharePoint?

I have read that SharePoint doesn't allow FTP access, which is what One-Click publishing uses.